# grouped multiple line equation?

Tags: amsmath, grouping

```
\begin{align*}
\langle H'_2 \rangle 
  &= \int_{0}^{b} |A|^2 sin^2(kr) \frac{-V_0r^4}{2b^4} dr\\
  &= \frac{(-V_0)}{2b^4}\int_{0}^{b} \frac{1-cos(2kr)}{2} r^4 dr \\
  &= \frac{(-V_0)}{2b^4}\frac{1}{2} 
     \left\lgroup \int_{0}^{b} r^4 dr 
     - \int_{0}^{b} r^4cos(2kr) dr \right\rgroup \\
  &= \frac{(-V_0)}{2b^4}\frac{1}{2} 
     \left\lgroup \frac{r^5}{5} - \frac{b^4sin(2kb)}{2k} 
     + \frac{1}{2k}\int_{0}^{b} 4r^3sin(2kr) dr \right\rgroup \\
  &= \frac{(-V_0)}{2b^4}\frac{1}{2} 
     \left\lgroup \frac{r^5}{5} - \frac{b^4sin(2kb)}{2k} 
     - \frac{4b^3(cos(2kb)-1)}{(2k)^2} 
     + \frac{4}{(2k)^2} \int_{0}^{b} 3r^2cos(2kr) dr \right\rgroup \\
  &= \frac{(-V_0)}{2b^4}\frac{1}{2} 
     \left\lgroup \frac{r^5}{5} - \frac{b^4sin(2kb)}{2k} 
     - \frac{(4b^3cos(2kb)-1)}{(2k)^2} + \frac{12b^2sin(2kb)}{(2k)^3} 
     - \frac{12}{(2k)^3} \int_{0}^{b} 2rsin(2kr) dr \right\rgroup\\       
  &= \frac{(-V_0)}{2b^4}\frac{1}{2} 
     \left\lgroup \frac{r^5}{5} - \frac{b^4sin(2kb)}{2k} 
     - \frac{(4b^3cos(2kb)-1)}{(2k)^2} 
     + \frac{12b^2sin(2kb)}{(2k)^3} \\
  &\quad+ \frac{24b(cos(2kb)-1)}{(2k)^4} - \frac{24}{(2k)^4} 
     \int_{0}^{b} cos(2kr) dr \right\rgroup
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Welcome! You cannot have a ` \\\` between the `\left\lgroup` and `\right\rgroup` in the last line of your equation.

Comment: You might be better off replacing `\left` and `\right` by `\Bigl` and `\Bigr`, which don't have this issue. (You may need to experiment to find the correct amount of `\big`ness.) By the way, I edited the title of the post. We don't do groping around here.

Comment: And, if you’re interested in good math typography, please write `\sin` and `\cos`, not just `sin` and `cos`. Plus, consider inserting `\,` (“thinspace”) before each and every `dr` term.

Answer (score 3):

You need `\biggl` and `\biggr` rather than `\left` and `\right`.

I'd prefer parentheses to `\lgroup` and `\rgroup`, though.

Here's a possibly better implementation, with slightly different alignment than proposed. I also fixed `\sin` and `\cos` instead of `sin` and `cos`; also added `\,` in front of `dr`. Finally, I changed `r^5` into `b^5`.

The split happens at the left parenthesis, so the role of the second line is clearer; between the main parts I added some vertical space for better separation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\langle H'_2 \rangle 
  &= \int_{0}^{b} |A|^2 \sin^2(kr) \frac{-V_0r^4}{2b^4} \,dr\\[1ex]
  &= \frac{(-V_0)}{2b^4}\int_{0}^{b} \frac{1-\cos(2kr)}{2} r^4 \,dr \\[2ex]
  &= \frac{(-V_0)}{2b^4}\frac{1}{2}
     \biggl\lgroup \int_{0}^{b} r^4 \,dr 
     - \int_{0}^{b} r^4\cos(2kr) \,dr \biggr\rgroup \\[2ex]
  &= \frac{(-V_0)}{2b^4}\frac{1}{2} 
     \biggl\lgroup \frac{b^5}{5} - \frac{b^4\sin(2kb)}{2k} 
     + \frac{1}{2k}\int_{0}^{b} 4r^3\sin(2kr) \,dr \biggr\rgroup \\[2ex]
  &= \frac{(-V_0)}{2b^4}\frac{1}{2}
     \biggl\lgroup\begin{aligned}[t]
     &\frac{b^5}{5} - \frac{b^4\sin(2kb)}{2k} - \frac{4b^3(\cos(2kb)-1)}{(2k)^2} \\
     &+ \frac{4}{(2k)^2} \int_{0}^{b} 3r^2\cos(2kr) \,dr \biggr\rgroup
     \end{aligned} \\[2ex]
  &= \frac{(-V_0)}{2b^4}\frac{1}{2} 
     \biggl\lgroup\begin{aligned}[t]
     & \frac{b^5}{5} - \frac{b^4\sin(2kb)}{2k} - \frac{(4b^3\cos(2kb)-1)}{(2k)^2} \\
     &+ \frac{12b^2\sin(2kb)}{(2k)^3} - \frac{12}{(2k)^3} \int_{0}^{b} 2r\sin(2kr) \,dr \biggr\rgroup
     \end{aligned} \\[2ex]
  &= \frac{(-V_0)}{2b^4}\frac{1}{2} 
     \biggl\lgroup\begin{aligned}[t]
     &\frac{b^5}{5} - \frac{b^4\sin(2kb)}{2k} 
     - \frac{(4b^3\cos(2kb)-1)}{(2k)^2} 
     + \frac{12b^2\sin(2kb)}{(2k)^3} \\
     &+ \frac{24b(\cos(2kb)-1)}{(2k)^4} - \frac{24}{(2k)^4} 
     \int_{0}^{b} \cos(2kr) \,dr \biggr\rgroup
     \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]